# the value ax is not an instance variable - what does it mean?

Tags: ocaml

Here is a part of my code.
I have the error “value ax is not an instance variable” at the line where the second `if` begins.

```
let avance x:ast list = List.fold_left (fun acc ast ->let (a,b) =  ast.positionA in 
                          let ax=a+.(cos a *. ast.vitesseA) 
                          and bx= b+.(sin b *.ast.vitesseA;) in (
if (ax>width/.2. && bx>height/.2.) then begin
   {couleur=ast.couleur;positionA=((-.width)/.2. +.(ax-.(width/.2.)),(-.height)/.2.+.(bx-.height/.2.));vitesseA=ast.vitesseA;taille=ast.taille;directionA=ast.directionA}::acc     
end else
if (ax<-width/.2. && bx<-height/.2.) then begin                                           
  {couleur=ast.couleur;positionA=(width/.2.-.(ax+.width/.2.),height/.2.-.(bx+.height/.2.);vitesseA=ast.vitesseA;taille=ast.taille;directionA=ast.directionA}::acc 
end else
```

Answer (score 0):

The symbol `<-` is an assignment operator for object instance variables. Your code suggests you expect it to be a comparison operator. Maybe you wanted `<=` or `<`.

Comment: I think he wants `< ~-.`.